# Laravel - Images not loading in production server, work fine in local

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm pretty new to working with laravel, and I just don't really understand how it deals with files. I followed the instructions in the documentation, used `php artisan storage:link` as instructed, but no go. I can't even see the images by going to their location in my url.

Here's my `config/filesystems` file:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
*/

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'img' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => storage_path('images')
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],

];
```

and this is how I'm calling the images in the template:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/images/icons/icon.png')}}">
```

I've checked, and the images are physically located at `ROOT/storage/app/public/images`.

What am I doing wrong here? And most importantly, why does this all work just fine in my local environment and not in my production server?

For additional info: The production server is hosted by Hostgator, in a subdomain of my company's main site. I don't know if that's an issue, as I said I am new to this whole thing.

Comment: Are you able to list the images in the public folder? (ls public/storage/images/icons). If the images are there I'm thinking it might be a problem with the redirect module in the host

Comment: If those are static assets (not uploaded), you could keep them in `ROOT/public/images` and show them with `<img src="{{asset('images/icons/icon.png')}}">`

Comment: Also check production server, from project root `ls -l public/ | grep storage` to see if symlink is there

Comment: This is what that command returned: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 agdpc941 agdpc941   49 Oct 19 15:57 storage -> /home/agdpc941/public_html/vbi/storage/app/public/`

Comment: Tthat looks good. Check file permissions, user and group with `ls -l public/storage/`

Comment: hi i explain this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625587/laravel-intervention-image-source-not-readable-on-deployment/60683285#60683285 cheers

Comment: I explain this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625587/laravel-intervention-image-source-not-readable-on-deployment/60683285#60683285 hope this help cheers

Answer (score 1):

The `asset` helper you are using in your Blade templates gives you the path for `public` assets, that is, assets located in the `public` folder of your Laravel application. Your static assets (such as logos, background images, etc) should be kept inside of your `public` directory, which is where your app is served from.

The `storage` directory is typically used for assets *uploaded* by a user in your application, such as a user uploading a new profile picture. To get the storage path, you would use the [`storage_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-storage-path) helper function to retrieve the path. Alternatively, you may use the [`Storage::url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-urls) method to retrieve a full URL to the storage path.