# laravel intervention image source not readable on deployment

Tags: laravel, image, filenotfoundexception, intervention

Image class intervention not readable!
can anyone help me that why image not readable error show on deployment when i upload new photos to laravel project,
which is totally fine in development environment but in production has this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqlSJ.png)

AND this my intervention code in controller

```
    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $nameWithExtension =  $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension =  $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = pathinfo($nameWithExtension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $newFileName = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;


        $upperExt = strtoupper($extension);
        if($upperExt == 'JPEG' OR $upperExt == 'PNG' OR $upperExt == 'JPG' OR $upperExt == 'GIF'){
            $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/doctor/',$newFileName);
            $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/doctor_small/',$newFileName);
            $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/doctor_small2/',$newFileName);

        //Resize image here 

            $thumbnailpath = public_path('storage/doctor_small/'.$newFileName);
            $img = Image::make($thumbnailpath)->resize(520, 668, function($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $img->save($thumbnailpath);

            $thumbnailpath2 = public_path('storage/doctor_small2/'.$newFileName);
            $img2 = Image::make($thumbnailpath2)->resize(100, 100)->save($thumbnailpath2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: post the full stackstrace please

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see this type of question, everyone answers that you should store it in the public folder of the project. says use this storage: link but it is not always like this, you should bear in mind that if you upload the folder in two different projects one public_html and another in a folder called for example my project things will be stored in the folder my project and laravel will search for them in public_html where they don't exist, a solution would be to put the whole project in public html by changing the .httacces this way

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews -Indexes
   </IfModule>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```